# How to provide users with a private copy of a pre-populated mediawiki site?

Tags: mediawiki

What are some reasonably good ways to offer users their own private version of a pre-populated mediawiki site? By "good way", I mean the most common way or the technically easiest way to give them a clone of the content and then allow them to edit and build the wiki as they like. A user would log into his or her account, select a topic of interest, and be given a wiki with several hundred pages of ready-made content to start working with and personalize.

My only ideas are to use an extension like [Simple Farm](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Simple_Farm) or to come to a service agreement with an existing wikifarm.

Comment: Have you considered using [backup](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Backing_up_a_wiki) and [restore](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Restoring_a_wiki_from_backup)?

Comment: [Meza](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Meza) can do unsupervised installs with content import. Haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Both backup/restore and Meza seem viable. I was hoping to learn more about packages designed to manage wikifarms and do something very similar to what I'm trying to do.